# Código Correto para selecionar e comparar

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu quero seleccionar * da tabela A que forem diferente da tabela B e tenho usado o seguinte código:

```
select * from Tabela A inner join Tabela B on A1 != B1 and A2 != B2 and A3 != B3
```

mas a memoria do computador vai ao limite e bloqueia o PC.

Tabela A

```
ID  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
1   1   2   3   4   XPTO1
2   2   3   4   5   XPTO2
3   3   4   5   6   XPTO3
4   4   5   6   7   XPTO4
5   5   6   7   8   XPTO5
6   6   7   8   9   XPTO6
7   7   8   9   10  XPTO7
8   8   9   10  11  XPTO8
9   9   10  11  12  XPTO9
10  10  11  12  13  XPTO10
11  11  12  13  14  XPTO11
12  12  13  14  15  XPTO12
13  13  14  15  16  XPTO13
14  14  15  16  17  XPTO14
15  15  16  17  18  XPTO15
16  16  17  18  19  XPTO16
17  17  18  19  20  XPTO17
18  18  19  20  21  XPTO18
19  19  20  21  22  XPTO19
20  20  21  22  23  XPTO20
```

Tabela B

```
ID  B1  B2  B3
1   1   2   3
2   5   6   7
3   9   10  11
4   13  14  15
5   17  18  19
```

Comment: Encontrará tudo o que precisa aqui : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 1):

### Use a cláusula [`EXISTS`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp)

No caso específico do seu exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM B
  WHERE A1 = B1
  AND A2 = B2
  AND A3 = B3)
```

Criei um [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cHLsFNa3jBjxeZTC1P7f6t/0) para você ver como funciona e testar se é o resultado que você espera.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM 'Tabela A' AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT `b.ID`
 FROM 'Tabela B' AS b
 WHERE b.B1 = a.A1
 AND b.B2 = a.A2
 AND b.B3 = a.A3);
```

Você faz uma sub-query que seleciona todos os itens da tabela B que são iguais aos itens da Tabela A, se a linha da Tabela A não existe no resultado desse sub-query, essa linha só existe na Tabela A.

Ou assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM 'Tabela A'
WHERE (A1, A2, A3) NOT IN
(SELECT B1, B2, B3
 FROM 'Tabela B');
```

Esse último eu vi agora nesse link, que tem um terceiro exemplo com `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, que o artigo diz ser o mais eficiente, mas creio que não sirva para você, porque você precisa de todos os campos da **Tabela A**:

> Union, Difference, Intersection in MySQL
>   http://eccdb2014bk.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/union-difference-intersection-in-mysql.html